# How do I get SAS to ignore missing variable names?

Tags: sas

If a SAS DATA step references a non-existant variable in a DROP,  KEEP,  or RENAME statement, it returns an error saying such and stops the DATA step due to this error.

How do I get SAS to keep going with the step when it references a non-existent variable? I assume there's an OPTION for this (?)  but I can't figure out what it's called if this is the case.

(I'm dealing with yearly datasets for which variables occasionally get added or deleted from year to year.)

Answer (score 4):

Try using:

`options dkricond=nowarn dkrocond=nowarn;`

First one is for input datasets, second one is for output datasets.

You might want to set these back to `warn` or `error` after you are done with the specific data steps where you know this will be an issue.

[SAS Manual page](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000208086.htm)